# Convert minutes to Minutes Hours and Days in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Is it possible in Thymeleaf to convert a long minute field to days, hrs, minutes? It is possible to do it on the controller and pass it. But I'm using a list and I have to iterate through the whole object and replace it with a new model class just to set minutes value as human-readable.

Update
@andrewjames answer worked as expected.

Did a bit more alteration to it to support plurals as well

```
<div
   th:with="days=${(minutes / (60 * 24))},
            hours=${(minutes - (days  * 60 * 24)) / ( 60)},
            minutes=${(minutes - (days * 60 * 24) - (hours * 60))},
            daysText=${days &gt; 0? days + (days &gt; 1? 'days ' :'day ') :''},
            hoursText=${hours &gt; 0? hours + (hours &gt; 1? 'hrs ':'hr ') :''},
            minutesText=${minutes &gt; 0? minutes+ (minutes &gt; 1? 'mins ':'min '):''}"
   th:text="${daysText} + ${hoursText} + ${minutesText}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use basic Thymeleaf arithmetic operators.

Assuming `${minutes}` contains a `long`:

```
<div th:with="days=${minutes / (60 * 24)},
              hours=${(minutes - (days * 60 * 24)) / ( 60)}"
     th:text="${days} + ' d ' 
              + ${hours} + ' h ' 
              + ${minutes} % 60 + ' m '">
</div>
```

Using `th:with` to create interim values makes it (slightly) easier to see how each portion is calculated.

For example, for a value of 123456 minutes you will get:

```
85 d 17 h 36 m
```

And for 123 minutes you will get:

```
0 d 2 h 3 m
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Help, It worked as expected. I have also updated my answer to support plurals. Kudos :)